# How to use shared prefs for keeping user logged in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, sharedpreferences

I have created a log in page for my flutter app that use firebase authentication. can someone help me to use shared preference in this so that user stays logged in even if he kills the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, in your login function, you should persist the data in sharePreference if validation is successfull;

```dart
/// your statefull code

void login() {
   // get the inputValues;

   // if validation success do this
   this._persistUserInfo();
}


void _persistUserInfo() async {
  final sharePrefsInstance = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  sharePrefsInstance .setString("email", EMAIL_VALUE);
  sharePrefsInstance .setString("password", _PASSWORD_VALUE);

}

/// your other statefull code;
```

the code above will persist the infromation on the device ;

to retrive the data in, in the **initState** of your **LoginScreen** do this

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 3),
      () async {
          final sharePrefsInstance = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

          final email = sharePrefsInstance.getString("email");
          final password  =  sharePrefsInstance.getString("password");

          if( email != null && password != null) {
             // navigate to your other screen since the user is authenticated
          }
      },
    );
  }
```